# JpaRepository with complex key class is failing validation with error "Validation failed for query for method" when using JPA syntax

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpa-2.1

I am trying to use the "out of the box" goodies of JPA and get data from DB to an object. It is working perfect when the JpaRepository is using a simple class as key, but for test cases when the key class is a bit complex, the jpa validation fails even for the simplest queries.

using a native_query=true will solve the issue, however I am not sure what I am doing wrong and what am I missing.

MyTestPK.java:

```java
package com.mytest.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class MyTestPK implements Serializable {
    private String type;
    private String name;
}
```

MyTest.java:

```java
package com.mytest.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_test")

@Data
@IdClass(MyTestPK.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "my_test_type", nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "my_test_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "my_test_misc")
    private String misc;
}
```

MyTestRepository.java:

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MyTestRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTest, MyTestPK> {
    @Query(value="SELECT m FROM MyTest m")
    List<MyTest> getAllObjs();
}
```

Getting the following error:
....
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List
com.mytest.dao.MyTestRepository.getAllObjs()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace instead of just a snippet and use proper code formatting for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @EmbeddedId and no need to define columns in the entity classes again.

MyTestPK.java:

```
package com.mytest.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class MyTestPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "my_test_type", nullable = false)
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "my_test_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

MyTest.java:

```
package com.mytest.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_test")
@Data
public class MyTest {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MyTestPK pk;

    @Column(name = "my_test_misc")
    private String misc;
}
```